# pig latin FILTER and GENERATE

Tags: apache-pig

I have a simple tuple (userid, country, amount, transactionid, date, crap1, crap2,crap3)

I am using FILTER to filter out some data and at the same time I want to drop some elements from the tuple. The reason they exist in the tuple is cause I need them at the some earlier point but not after the filter.

currently i am doing

```
B = FILTER A by date == 'xxxx';
C = FOREACH B GENERATE name, country, tranactionid;
```

Is it possible to do it in one statement (to speed up the query), because as I understand FOREACH + FILTER + GENERATE only work on nested bags.

Comment: Why you are sure that it will speed up the query while there is a powerful optimizer in Pig ? Do you check your explain plans ?

Comment: i assumed that there will be only one run through the tuples instead of 2 times

Comment: I am still figuring out how to interpret the 'explain' plans

Answer (score 0):

Not possible..

```
FILTER alias  BY expression;
```

and

```
FOREACH { gen_blk | nested_gen_blk } [AS schema];
```